# typescript: Function generic types will not be evaluated by conditional types

Tags: typescript, generics, types, conditional-statements, calculation

My code:

```js
type getType<t> = t extends string ? string : number
function fun<A extends string>(a: A) {
    var x: getType<A> = 'abc'
}
```

`getType` is a type calculation. If the input type is `string`, return `string`, otherwise return `number`.

In the function `fun`, there is a variable `x` of `getType<A>` type.

Because I stated `A extends string`, It is logical to say that `getType<A>` is a `string`.

but TypeScript will not infer this. TypeScript complains: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'getType<A>'`.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there's a potential improvement for TypeScript to understand that both constraints will be true. I don't see a way around this without making it `x: string` or `x: getType<A & string>`. :(